# Delete a file after download RestAPI

Tags: java, spring

How can I delete the file after calling this method, I am calling this method from a web service using Spring GET Http. I want to delete the file once it is sent to the client.

```
    public File download(String filePath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
           return file;
           //this line will never run !!!
           Files.delete(filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can always move things around and place the delete in a `finally` block, but that doesn't seem safe to me. It would cause the function to have side effects. Why not just delete the file after you've returned it in the calling method? Wouldn't that be cleaner?

Comment: @mnestorov the calling method after calling download send the file to the client. i'm not sure how can i delete the file after return